# Move to else statement based on variable update outside if-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

Folks, this may be small query but i am stuck in here, anyone could help me understand my requirement will be appreciated.

```
check = True
if check:
    for i in dict:
        if i in another_dict:
            do something
        else:
            check = False

else:
    status = True

if status:
    do something

else:
```

Initially I am assigned True(bool) value to a variable outside IF-ELSE statement, I want to move to else statement if I update the same variable from inside IF statement.

(i.e ) in the above code,
I want to continue with main else statement if the variable "check" = False

Answer (score 1):

Just use another `if`. If `check` was updated inside the first `if`, it will go into the second `if`:

```py
check = True
status = False

if check:
    for i in dct:
        if i in another_dict:
            do_something()
        else:
            check = False

if not check:
    do_something()
    status = True

if status:
    do_something()
```

Comment: I guess you'd need `if not check:` here to achieve what OP described.

Comment: After this IF-ELSE statement there is another IF statement that I am using, So in order to use another IF-ELSE I want to close this IF statement using else right.

Comment: @matszwecja - thanks, I slightly misunderstood OP's question

Comment: @iltech You don't need to use `if-else`, you can use just `if`

Comment: @iltech - you can have an `if` on it's own in Python, it doesn't need to be closed with an `else`

Comment: I guess if you really wanted to, just write `else: pass`, but this is really not necessary.

Comment: I have updated my code in question, I have another IF to be continued.

Comment: it cannot be pass. Since based on the "check" variable value if its False I need to move to else statement.

Comment: @iltech - **don't use `else`, use another `if`**

Comment: @iltech another `if` doesn't change anything. If your `if` is entered, corresponding `else` will not be. Use `if not check` instead.

Comment: I cannot use another IF, because there is a variable I am using inside else statement, is i am using as condition in next If statement. so It throws error like (Local variable 'variable name' may be referenced before assignment)

Comment: @matszwecja, Updated my question check why we cant use another IF

Comment: @TheThonnu check why we cant use another IF in my updated code in question

Comment: @iltech - updated. Just initialise `status` before

Comment: like? how? @TheThonnu

Comment: @iltech - look at my answer, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

To go to the outer else you will need to break out of the loop you are in.

```
for i in dict:
```

However, even if the loop finishes, "check" will not be checked again because it already has been once. To understand it better, we have already crossed the line:

```
if check
```

And we will not be coming back to it, since there is no loop.

Considering all this, the best solution is to add another check at the end of the code to see if check == false and do whatever you have to do.

```
check = True
if check:
    for i in dict:
        if i in another_dict:
            do something
        else:
            check = False

else:
    do something

if not check
    do something
```

Comment: `!check` gives a `SyntaxError`. In Python you use `not check`

Comment: This will also cause `do something` to be executed twice should `check` happen to be initially False.

Answer (score -1):

Use check as global variable..
.you change the value of a global variable inside a function, refer to the variable by using the global keyword:

```
x = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.